# Moving the content of group of cell to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML Table which is similar to the one shown (demo.jpg) in the below link.
http://www.2shared.com/photo/EF948V7-/demo.html

I'm trying to create a functionality where group of cells can be dragged simultaneously and shifted to another location horizontally. When the group of cell is shifted to new location, the Total Available should change accordingly.

Eg. In the attachment I should be able to move the Group 3 (7th April and 8th April) cell to new dates say  2nd April and 3rd April and the Total Available for 2nd and 3rd should decrease by 10.

How to achieve this using jQuery or JavaScript?

Thanks and Regards,
Shijesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap the contents in your TD with a DIV, it's actually pretty simple.

You need to use [jquery droppapble](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) to make the DIVs in the TD droppable in other TDs. Then when someone drags it around and drops it in a TD, you can add your callback function in the `drop` event and handle it there.

Comment: thank you.

The content is wrapped inside div.. 
<td class="droppable"><div class="draggable">10</div></td>
I am able to drag and drop individual cell content.

However, I need to move the groups of cells together and change the total available.How to achive this part...

Comment: It's the same logic. When you do the drop, all you have to do is use jquery traversal (using `.parent()` and `siblings()`) and get the other divs in that column. Just need to put the code into the `drop` event and possibly the `start` event

Comment: Ah... got it..
One more question on related notes ... Its just a wish list ...
Suppose I'm dragging group to the left.. is it possible that all cell of the group follow the drag and total available is updated ... before dropping it to final location....

Comment: If you want functionality like that, you could write custom code and put it in the `start` event of draggable or use a plugin like this : http://www.danvk.org/wp/dragtable/